# /config/database.yml in .gitignore on deploy /config/database.yml not found should use /shared/database.yml instead, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I followed the docs on cap + nginx + unicorn but have some problems to understand how to do the database deployment correctly.

- /config/database.yml should not be in the git repo ( preferable )
- on production server in /shared/database.yml you place the database.yml
- Problem is that on deploy it still looks for /config/database.yml

**How can I make my deploy.rb grab the /shared/database.yml instead?**
search high and low for this to no avail :(

deploy.rb

```
    # config/deploy.rb
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :scm, :git
set :repository, "root@109.etc:/srv/paintings.git"
set :branch, "origin/master"
set :migrate_target, :current
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :rails_env, "production"
set :deploy_to, "/srv/paintings"
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

set :user, "root"
set :group, ""
set :use_sudo, true
default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :port, 5984
ssh_options[:port] = 5984


role :web, "109.etc"
role :app, "109.etc"
role :db, "109.etc", :primary => true

set(:latest_release) { fetch(:current_path) }
set(:release_path) { fetch(:current_path) }
set(:current_release) { fetch(:current_path) }

set(:current_revision) { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD").strip }
set(:latest_revision) { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD").strip }
set(:previous_revision) { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD@{1}").strip }

default_environment["RAILS_ENV"] = 'production'

#default_environment["PATH"]         = "/bin/bash"
#default_environment["GEM_HOME"]     = "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125"
#default_environment["GEM_PATH"]     = "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125"
#default_environment["RUBY_VERSION"] = "ruby 1.9.3p125"
#default_run_options[:shell] = 'bash'

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Deploy your application"
  task :default do
    update
    restart
  end

  desc "Setup your git-based deployment app"
  task :setup, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    dirs = [deploy_to, shared_path]
    dirs += shared_children.map { |d| File.join(shared_path, d) }
    run "#{try_sudo} mkdir -p #{dirs.join(' ')} && #{try_sudo} chmod g+w #{dirs.join(' ')}"
    run "git clone #{repository} #{current_path}"
  end

  task :cold do
    update
    migrate
  end

  task :update do
    transaction do
      update_code
    end
  end

  desc "Update the deployed code."
  task :update_code, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "cd #{current_path}; git fetch origin; git reset --hard #{branch}"
    finalize_update
  end

  desc "Update the database (overwritten to avoid symlink)"
  task :migrations do
    transaction do
      update_code
    end
    migrate
    restart
  end

  task :finalize_update, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "chmod -R g+w #{latest_release}" if fetch(:group_writable, true)

    # mkdir -p is making sure that the directories are there for some SCM's that don't
    # save empty folders
    run <<-CMD
      rm -rf #{latest_release}/log #{latest_release}/public/system #{latest_release}/tmp/pids &&
      mkdir -p #{latest_release}/public &&
      mkdir -p #{latest_release}/tmp &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/log #{latest_release}/log &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/system #{latest_release}/public/system &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/pids #{latest_release}/tmp/pids
    CMD

    if fetch(:normalize_asset_timestamps, true)
      stamp = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M.%S")
      asset_paths = fetch(:public_children, %w(images stylesheets javascripts)).map { |p| "#{latest_release}/public/#{p}" }.join(" ")
      run "find #{asset_paths} -exec touch -t #{stamp} {} ';'; true", :env => {"TZ" => "UTC"}
    end
  end

  desc "Zero-downtime restart of Unicorn"
  task :restart, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    #run "kill -s USR2 'cat /srv/paintings/shared/pids/unicorn.pid'"
    run "kill -s USR2 'cat /srv/paintings/shared/tmp/unicorn.pid'"
  end

  desc "Start unicorn"
  task :start, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    run "cd #{current_path} ; bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D"
  end

  desc "Stop unicorn"
  task :stop, :except => {:no_release => true} do
    #run "kill -s QUIT 'cat /srv/paintings/shared/pids/unicorn.pid'"
    run "kill -s QUIT 'cat /tmp/unicorn.pid'"
  end

  namespace :rollback do
    desc "Moves the repo back to the previous version of HEAD"
    task :repo, :except => {:no_release => true} do
      set :branch, "HEAD@{1}"
      deploy.default
    end

    desc "Rewrite reflog so HEAD@{1} will continue to point to at the next previous release."
    task :cleanup, :except => {:no_release => true} do
      run "cd #{current_path}; git reflog delete --rewrite HEAD@{1}; git reflog delete --rewrite HEAD@{1}"
    end

    desc "Rolls back to the previously deployed version."
    task :default do
      rollback.repo
      rollback.cleanup
    end
  end
end

def run_rake(cmd)
  run "cd #{current_path}; #{rake} #{cmd}"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using a very similar `deploy.rb`, but I have one more symbolic link in my `finalize_update` method:

```
ln -sf #{shared_path}/database.yml #{latest_release}/config/database.yml
```